# Flutter: How can I create rounded Elevated buttons with ButtonStyle()?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

I want to create a rounded elevated button that changes color when pressed. So far I've used ButtonStyle() to change the color, using the code:

```
style: ButtonStyle(
                   backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) { 
       if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
            return Colors.black;}
       return Colors.red;}))
```

This changes the color from red to black when touched.
But I cant find a way to resize the button and create a rounded edges. I know how to do it with ElevatedButton.styleForm(), but with styleForm() I dont know how to make it change color when touched. Is there any other way I can do it with styleForm, or fuse both styles in one code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using style property you can create your own shape.

```
 SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)))),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => SignUp()));
                        },
                        child: const Text("Sign up here")),
                  ),
```